# How to get the first letter of two words that are linked with a specific character

Tags: php, regex

could you please tell me the way to get the first letter of two words that are linked with a specific character. For instance: **hello_world** I want to convert it to **h_w**

I tried to get the first letter of the two words. But I don't know the way to keep the underscore between them

```
$str = 'hellow_world';
echo preg_replace("/(\w)[^_]*?(?:_|$)/", "$1", $str);
```

Comment: Maybe `preg_replace('~(?<=[^\W_])[^\W_]+~', '', $text)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the following with nothing:

```
(?:\b|_)[a-z]     # Find a word boundary or an underscore followed by a letter,
\K                # forfeit both of them,
[a-z]*            # then match 0 or more letters.
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Y5z5g2/2).

Alternatively, you can match the whole word and replace it with the first letter using `$1`:

```
(?<=\b|_)         # Match something preceded by a word boundary or an underscore
([a-z])[a-z]*     # that is 1 or more letters, the first of which we capture.
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Y5z5g2/3).

If you only want to match words linked with underscore, add a lookahead:

```
(?:\b(?=[a-z]+_)|_)[a-z]\K[a-z]*
(?<=\b(?=[a-z]+_)|_)([a-z])[a-z]*
```

...in which `` means "match a word boundary *iff* it is followed by 1+ characters and an underscore".

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Y5z5g2/4).

Comment: In both cases this converts `'posuere lacus'` to `'p l'` (end of last of example at links, but certainly not the only such string), whereas I do not believe that string was to be altered as it contained no underscore.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Add another lookahead then: [`(?<=\b(?=[a-z]+_)|_)([a-z])[a-z]*`](https://regex101.com/r/Y5z5g2/4).

Comment: Your revised regex appears correct to me, but I suggest you edit your answer and the regex at the link. Consider also paring down the example text at the link to reduce redundancy.

Comment: Answer edited, but I'll leave the text as-is since those links are permanent and I don't want to create new ones.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep only the first character of a word not being an underscore, you can use `\B` to assert a non word boundary not preceded by `_` and match 1+ word chars other than `_`

Note that `\w` can also match `_` which you can exclude with a negated character class `[^\W_]`

```
\B(?<!_)[^\W_]+
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fZOK7U/1).

---

If the words must have at least one `_` where there is a word character before and after the underscore, you can make use of the `\G` anchor and 2 capture groups.

```
(?:\b([^\W_])[^\W_]*|\G(?!^))(_[^\W_])[^\W_]*
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `\b([^\W_])` A word boundary, capture a single word char other than `_` in **group 1**
  - `[^\W_]*` Match optional word chars other than `_`
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the current postion at the end of the previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `(_[^\W_])` Capture `_` and a single word char other than `_` in **group 2**
- `[^\W_]*` Match optional word chars other than `_`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qq3W8R/1) and a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/g2Brl)

```
$regex = '/(?:\b([^\W_])[^\W_]*|\G(?!^))(_[^\W_])[^\W_]*/m';
$str = 'hello_world
this_is_a_test_string

ab_bc_cd
a_b_c
a_bb_c
a_b_cc
aa_b_c

this_is_
this_
this
Hi there';
$subst = "$1$2";

echo preg_replace($regex, "$1$2", $str);
```

Output

```
h_w
t_i_a_t_s

a_b_c
a_b_c
a_b_c
a_b_c
a_b_c

t_i_
this_
this
Hi there
```